# Error: NodejsNpmEsbuildBuilder:EsbuildBundle - Esbuild Failed: X [ERROR] Could not resolve "aws-sdk"

Tags: node.js, typescript, aws-lambda, aws-sam

**Problem:**

I'm trying to build Typescript code which will be deployed to AWS Lambda. However upon Aws Sam build I'm getting error as mentioned in the title. Following is the exact error.

```
Building codeuri: D:\AWS\demo-app\hello-world runtime: nodejs16.x metadata: {'BuildMethod': 'esbuild', 'BuildProperties': {'Minify': True, 'Target': 'es2020', 'EntryPoints': ['app.ts']}} architecture: x86_64 functions: HelloWorldFunction
Running NodejsNpmEsbuildBuilder:CopySource
Running NodejsNpmEsbuildBuilder:NpmInstall
Running NodejsNpmEsbuildBuilder:EsbuildBundle

Build Failed
Error: NodejsNpmEsbuildBuilder:EsbuildBundle - Esbuild Failed: X [ERROR] Could not resolve "aws-sdk"

    app.ts:2:21:
      2 │ import * as AWS from 'aws-sdk';
        ╵                      ~~~~~~~~~

  You can mark the path "aws-sdk" as external to exclude it from the bundle, which will remove this error.

1 error
child_process.js:830
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Command failed: C:\Users\AyubJamal\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\esbuild\node_modules\esbuild-windows-64\esbuild.exe app.ts --bundle --platform=node --outdir=D:\AWS\demo-app\.aws-sam\build\HelloWorldFunction --format=cjs --minify --target=es2020
    at checkExecSyncError (child_process.js:790:11)
    at Object.execFileSync (child_process.js:827:15)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\AyubJamal\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\esbuild\bin\esbuild:209:28)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1085:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1114:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:950:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:790:12)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:76:12)
    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47 {
  status: 1,
  signal: null,
  output: [ null, null, null ],
  pid: 23712,
  stdout: null,
  stderr: null
}
```

So I searched and found out that my node_modules didn't have **aws-sdk** so I install it with

```
npm install aws-sdk
```

even I installed

```
npm install --save-dev @types/node
```

but somehow esbuild fails, the error mentions to mark the path as external, can someone please guide how to mark it external? I'm sharing my tsconfig.json as below

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
      "target": "es2020",
      "strict": true,
      "preserveConstEnums": true,
      "noEmit": true,
      "sourceMap": false,
      "module":"es2015",
      "moduleResolution":"node",
      "esModuleInterop": true, 
      "skipLibCheck": true,
      "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,  
    },
    "exclude": ["node_modules", "**/*.test.ts"]
  }
```

Comment: I ran into a similar issue using `import { SecretsManagerClient } from "@aws-sdk/client-secrets-manager";`. My mistake was that I had installed this package as a dev dependency. The problem went way when I moved it from `devDependencies` to `dependencies` in `package.json`.

Answer (score 7):

Add `External:` property to Metadata.BuildProperties in "template.yaml"

ex.)

```
Metadata: # Manage esbuild properties
  BuildMethod: esbuild
  BuildProperties:
    Minify: true
    Target: "es2020"
    Sourcemap: true
    EntryPoints: 
      - app.ts
    # ==== add below ====
    External:
      - "@aws-sdk/lib-dynamodb"
      - "@aws-sdk/client-dynamodb"
```

[Metadata properties in AWS Documents](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/en_us/serverless-application-model/latest/developerguide/serverless-sam-cli-using-build-typescript.html)

Answer (score 4):

for anyone still experiencing this. Delete the `.aws-sam/` folder (which caches `node_modules/`) and re-run your build command.

That fixed it instantly for me. Nothing else seemed to do anything.

Specific error I had (with `@aws-sdk/client-iot`)

```
Running NodejsNpmEsbuildBuilder:EsbuildBundle                                                                

Build Failed
Error: NodejsNpmEsbuildBuilder:EsbuildBundle - Esbuild Failed: ✘ [ERROR] Could not resolve "@aws-sdk/client-iot"

    myfolder/myfile.ts:2:43:
      2 │ import {IoTClient} from '@aws-sdk/client-iot';
        ╵                                            ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

  You can mark the path "@aws-sdk/client-iot" as external to exclude it from the bundle, which will remove this error.

1 error
make: *** [build] Error 1
```

Comment: This is fantastic non of the above worked but this one worked...good job and thanks for sharing